# How to link the scrollbar position of a set of controls?

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll

I write a class Scope inherit UserControl. I use some Scope to draw some figures that have the same time stamp. So I want to scroll all Scope when I scroll one of them.
I think I just make OnScroll method static, but it's not work.

What should I do?

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: wpf, winforms, webforms, mvc?

Comment: So, you have two controls and want to link their scrolblars?

Comment: yep. actually I have unfixed number of these controls.

Comment: of course, each UI framework have different APIs and implementations.

Comment: In fact I am more concerned about the method

Comment: So you have a design question but you said your solution didn't work. I guess it didn't work because of something specific to winforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have a CompositeScroll class with method AddScrollbar. This class suscribes to the OnScroll of each scrollbar you add and make the others change its position in there. Something like this:

```
public class CompositeScroll
{
    private List<Scrollbar> scrollbars = new List<Scrollbars>();

    public void AddScrollbar(Scrollbar scrollbar)
    {
        scrollbars.Add(scrollbar);
        scrollbar.OnScroll += OnScroll;
    }

    private void OnScroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var current = (Scrollbar)sender;
        var scrollbarsToMove = scrollbars.Where(x => x != current);

        foreach(var scrollbar in scrollbarsToMove)
            scrollbar.Position = current.Position;
    }
}

public class MyForm : Form
{
    private CompositeScroll compositeScroll = new CompositeScroll();        

    public MyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponents();
        compositeScroll.AddScrollbar(scrollbar1);
        compositeScroll.AddScrollbar(scrollbar2);
        compositeScroll.AddScrollbar(scrollbar3);
        compositeScroll.AddScrollbar(scrollbar4);
    }
}
```

This is an idea, you can change the Scrollbar type with the one you are using that contains teh scrollbars (Maybe a plain old UserControl).

Hope it helps.

Comment: As according to the question the UI technology doesn't matter, it's in a sort of pseudo code. I know the Winforms API is not that way, it's just to make the point.

Comment: Nice work. I have solved issue following your idea. It's critical that make all controls respond the same event.

Answer (score 0):

I made a quick test with 2 vertical scroll bars set side by side. I attached the following form's handler to each scrollbar's `Scroll` event in order to make each one follow the other:

```
private void vScrollBar_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
  var otherScrollBar = sender == vScrollBar1 ? vScrollBar2 : vScrollBar1;
  otherScrollBar.Value = e.NewValue;
}
```

In your case (user controls), I would:

1. In your `Scope` control: Expose a `Scroll` event and a `ScrollPosition` property. The event forwards internal Scope scrollbar events to the form.
2. In the form, subcribe to the event of each `Scope` control (One common handler for all `Scope` occurences, as shown above)
3. In the handler, set `ScrollPosition` for each `Scope!=sender` according to the scroll event args

Notes:

1. Setting the scrollbar's value programmatically doesn't fire the `Scroll` event on that scrollbar. Hence this code doesn't enter an infinite loop.
2. Of course, if `Scope` features both horiz and vert scrollbars, you'll want to 2 events (or an event args which says horiz or vert) and 2 properties: `HorizScrollPosition` and `VertScrollPosition`.